# Convert ArcGIS labels to a shapefile for displaying in Tableau

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, labeling, annotation, tableau

I have building polygons in ArcGIS Pro that I have setup labelling on to describe what occupies each building. The labels are setup in a way where they’re nicely fitting and sizing within their polygon.

I’d essentially like to repeat this in Tableau but Tableau is woeful at labelling features - there’s no advanced placement settings like in Arc so it currently looks a mess in my Tableau dashboard.

Therefore, I am wondering if I can somehow get these labels in a format (eg polyline shapefile) so I could display them in Tableau essentially as their own layer. I know I can convert to annotation in ArcGIS Pro but I still cannot then export that to polyline feature.

Or if there is another way/format I could go about getting neat labels in Tableau?

Comment: Try https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/feature-outline-masks.htm with Exact option

Comment: Yes, labels to annotations first

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP - seems to be working well.